# What are intvectors and how to read/use them?

Tags: php, date, icu

How do i apply the integers/intvectors formatted in a ICU data file...

For example;

```
    US{
        {
            id{"USD"}
            from:intvector{ /** 1792-01-01  */
                -1308,
                694083168,
            }
        }
```

Can i format these to a human-readable "from" date, e.g. 1792-01-01 in PHP?

Thanks

// Roland

Edit:
I have the integers in PHP;

```
["US"] => array(3)
{
  [0] => array(2)
  {
    ["from"] => array(2)
    {
      [0] => int(-1308)
      [1] => int(694083168)
    }
    ["id"] => string(3) "USD"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the ICU generator tool that you're using? Of the formats listed here ( http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata ), which are you using?

Comment: I did a checkout of http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/source/data/ and compiled the resource files in PHP using the genrb command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the intvectors are just an array of ints.

Boldface: **You should not be reading the ICU data directly !!!**  Use APIs.

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucurr_8h.html is the API which works with this data.

If you really want to get at this data directly,

- get it from CLDR: http://cldr.unicode.org/ such as the
- Currency supplemental data http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml  and you can
- read the charts http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/detailed_territory_currency_information.html  and especially  the
- spec http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec

But please don't read the internal ICU data directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use json-decode for this task.

Comment: Eh.. i mean how can i **format** -1308 and 694083168 into a date?

What does these integers mean?